# Returning a string made by odd index number of the string

Tags: java, string, indexing, substring

The Return type is a String and no Input parameters. I have to go through the instance variable called str and return a string that is put together by odd index number of the string.

i forgot to mention that it has to be a while loop

Example: str = "Poland"

```
     then the method should return "oad" because P is an even number, o is odd, l is even, a is odd, n is even, d is odd.
```

I so far have come up with this

```
public class MeWhileLoop
{
    
    public int a, b;
    public String str;

    public String OddNumChar(){
        
        int index = 0;
        str = "Poland";
        while(index < str.length()){
            
            System.out.println(str.substring(index, index+1));
            index++;
            
        }
        System.out.println();
        return str;
    }

}
```

I'm just stuck because the index+1 won't take out the odd letters or any letter at all and I have no clue why.

Comment: it has to be a while loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
String res = "";

// start at second character and then increment by 2
for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); i += 2) {
    res += str.charAt(i);
}

return res;
```

---

This might have better performance for larger strings:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str.length() / 2);

for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); i += 2) {
    sb.append(str.charAt(i));
}

return sb.toString();
```

---

If you really need while loop for some reason:

```
String res = "";

int i = 1;
while (i < str.length()) {
    res += str.charAt(i);
    i += 2;
}

return res;
```

Comment: i forgot to mention that it has to be a while loop

Comment: Every `for` loop can be easily transformed into `while` loop. I've added that to the answer.